# SQL equivalent for First

Tags: sql-server

I understand that there is not an equivalent that works the same as access so I am actually just looking for help in writing the query to perform the same task.  Basically, here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT PR.SSN as SSN, 
    MIN(PR.[Last Name]) as [Last Name],
    MIN(PR.Address) as [Address], 
    MIN(PR.City) as [City], 
    MIN(PR.State) as [State], 
    MIN(PR.Zip) as [Zip],
    MIN(cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date)) as [Pay Begin Period],
    MAX(cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date)) as [Pay End Period],
FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] PR
WHERE (cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date) > '1/1/2013' AND
        cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date) < '12/31/2013')
GROUP BY PR.SSN
```

This query will retrieve the earliest [Pay Begin Period] and the latest [Pay End Period] for each SSN.  However, I want the [Last Name] retrieved to be from the earliest [Pay Begin Period].  In some cases, people will have a [Last Name] change.  We only want the earliest/first one ever recorded.

So I would like to change this line:

```
MIN(PR.[Last Name]) as [Last Name],
```

to something like this:

```
(SELECT [Last Name] 
 FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] 
 WHERE [Pay Begin Period] = Min([Pay Begin Period])),
```

I realize that does not work, but that is the best way I can explain what I am looking for.

Comment: Is this for [tag:sql-server]? The [tag:sql] tag is for the language, and if you want help with a specific product, that tag does tell you you should add a product specific tag.

Comment: Unfortunately MS Access allows for the first item added to a table to be returned but there is no inherent order of data in a table, you have to use order by to determine the correct order.  If you edited your question with some sample data and then the desired result it might be easier to determine the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the tag to sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this by enumerating the rows for each `SSN` and then choosing the first one:

```
SELECT PR.SSN as SSN, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PR.[Last Name] END) as [Last Name],
    MIN(PR.Address) as [Address], 
    MIN(PR.City) as [City], 
    MIN(PR.State) as [State], 
    MIN(PR.Zip) as [Zip],
    MIN(cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date)) as [Pay Begin Period],
    MAX(cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date)) as [Pay End Period],
FROM (SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PR.SSN ORDER BY [Pay Begin Period]) as seqnum
      FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] PR
     ) pr
WHERE (cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date) > '1/1/2013' AND
        cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date) < '12/31/2013')
GROUP BY PR.SSN;
```

`row_number()` is a ranking function that assigns sequential numbers to rows within a group.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause, so each `SSN` value gets its own sequence of numbers.  The ordering is specified by the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: This bit `MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PR.[Last Name] END)` is very nice.

Comment: I retract my statement, I made a mistake.

Comment: So Partition By is basically like Group By right?  We're are telling it which sets of data get their own set of enumerations?  If that is the case, can we also do multiple Partition By?  Say we want Partition By SSN and Partition By another grouped by value like [Store Number].

Comment: @LeythG . . . window/analytic functions (what you are calling `partition by`) are similar to aggregation functions (`group by`) in the sense that each defines a set of rows for a particular operation.  They differ from aggregation because they do not reduce the number of rows to 1.  They simply perform the operation and include the results for each row.